# how to use floating lable for ion-select

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

if i am using input tag with floating lable it was comming like phone tag like below image.I use select tag with floating lable it was comming like country tag.

i want country also come like phone tag.How can i get look and feel same as like phone tag.

[image]
html code

```
<ion-item width-50 >
  <ion-label floating>Phone</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="tel"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item width-50>
  <ion-label floating>Country</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="country">
    <ion-option>{{country}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: If any one know this please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that with the `floating` label. In terms of *look and feel*, you can pre-select the first option of the select element, in order to avoid that field being *empty like that*. At least that's what we do in our forms to make them look nicer.

Another option could be to design the form like you can see [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/#select), and that way you can make the input fields look the same as the select elements.