# Ionic 2 input highlight

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic2, highlight

I'm trying to make a form but I'm stuck trying to change the highlight color when an item has focus (see picture). I tried Using this line of code in my Sass which I've found in the Ionic docs, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how this works?

```
$text-input-md-highlight-color: #000000;
```

[image: I suppose the highlight-color should change the text-color and the bottom-border-color]

Comment: where did you override the variable? in variable.scss?

Comment: No I wrote it in my formpage sass, that fixed it, Thank you! But it seems like it only changes the line at the bottom.

Comment: ok.. but it will be a global change in variable.scss

Comment: That's no problem for me.

Comment: ok.. adding as answer

Comment: I have another question as well maybe you know that too. As you can see I used floating labels but as I didn't use an ion-input but an ion-select for Language it isn't working there. Do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137333/how-to-use-floating-lable-for-ion-select that is not possible

Comment: Mmmh okay, thanks anyway man :)

Comment: no problem.....:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to overide the SASS in `variable.scss` file for it take affect.
See more [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/).
Put:

```
$text-input-md-highlight-color: #000000;
```

in `src/theme/variable.scss`.

Comment: Your answer save me

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<div class="container">

  <h2>Design in CSS3<small>Inputs</small></h2>

  <form>

    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Name</label>
    </div>

    <div class="group">      
      <input type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label>Email</label>
    </div>

  </form>



</div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/rekfwax3/)